# Зависает recv при получении данных, WinSock!

Tags: smtp, winsock, c++

Ситуация такая. Подключаюсь к smtp.mail.ru. Порт 25. Шлю "EHLO Ivan\r\n". 
Вот функция моей обвертки для сокета:

```
std::string jSocket::RecvData()
{
    std::string sresult;
    int iResult = 0;
    int buffsize = 1024;
    char* buff = new char[buffsize];    
    do
    {
            //После 1 итерации цикла, все останавливается на следующей строке
        iResult = recv((*this).sock, buff, buffsize, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)        
            for (int i = 0; i < iResult; ++i)           
                sresult.append(1, buff[i]);
    }
    while (iResult > 0);
    return sresult;
}
```

В дебагере видно, что сначала я получаю 120 символов, после возвращаюсь на эту самую  строку и все просто стоит. Из-за чего это?

P.S. Если не трудно, раскритикуйте заодно функцию получения данных.

Comment: <a href=http://www.insidepro.com/kk/006/006r.shtml>Читаем</a> до просветления

Comment: Читал. Я бы наверно и не задал вопрос, если бы с HTTP запросами было все хорошо.

Comment: Почитал вдумчиво. Выходит, что recv ничего не получила и поэтому не возвращает управление? Или тоже опять не то?

Comment: _Выходит, что recv ничего не получила и поэтому не возвращает управление?_<p>
Думаю, что да.

Comment: Хм, как тогда лучше частями получить ответ? Или писать под конкретный протокол? (Например в http пустая строка в конце).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string jSocket::RecvData()
{
    std::string sresult;
    int iResult = 0;
    int buffsize = 1024;
    char* buff = new char[buffsize];
    u_long arg; 
    do
    {
            ioctlsocket((*this).sock, FIONREAD, &arg);
            if (arg == 0)
                    break;
            if (arg > buffsize)
                    arg = buffsize;
            iResult = recv((*this).sock, buff, arg, 0);
            if (iResult > 0)        
                    for (int i = 0; i < iResult; ++i)           
                        sresult.append(1, buff[i]);
    }
    while (iResult > 0);
    return sresult;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы работаете с SMTP сервером по SMTP/ESMTP протоколу.  В нем происходит обмен сообщениями (конкретно строками, которые завершаются \r\n) между сервером и клиентом.

Начало: (S: - посылка сервера, C: - клиента)

```
S:  220 Sendmail ESMTP version ... ready ....
C:  HELO xaxa.ru
S:  250 HELO , Pleased to meet you
C:  MAIL FROM: abc@xaxa ...
```

и т.д. в соответствии с RFC822 и последующими. На всякий случай, кусочек кода клиента.
Надеюсь из debug() и error() в нем все будет понятно.

```
  if (!rfile || !wfile) {  // потоки на чтение и запись, переоткрытые (fdopen(sock))
    error(SYSERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. Can't re-open a stream file.");
    rc = -1; goto LRET1;
  }

  char stri[MAXLENSMTPLINE];
  debug(204,"SMTP: Waiting for Greeting");
  if(ACSAlarm || // Внешняя переменная, доступная обработчику SIGALRM
     !fgets(stri,sizeof(stri),rfile)) {
    //    if (ACSAlarm) errno = ETIME;
    error(SYSERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. Can't get Sendmail ready.");
    rc = -1; goto LRET1;
  }
  delete_crnl(stri);
  debug(204,"SMTP: <--- \"%s\"", stri);
  if(stri[0] != '2' ) {
    error(ERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. Sendmail ready : %s",stri); 
    rc=4; goto LRET1;
  }

  extern char     *acs_defhello;
  if(ACSAlarm || 
     fprintf(wfile,
     "HELO %s\r\n",acs_defhello) == EOF || fflush(wfile) == EOF) {
    //    if (ACSAlarm) errno = ETIME;
    error(SYSERRMSG,"Sendmail. Can't send HELO command.");
    rc = -1; goto LRET1;
  }
  debug(204,"SMTP: ---> HELO %s",acs_defhello);
  if(ACSAlarm ||
     !fgets(stri,sizeof(stri),rfile)) {
    //    if (ACSAlarm) errno = ETIME;
    error(SYSERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. Can't get reply on HELO.");
    rc = -1; goto LRET1;
  }
  delete_crnl(stri);
  debug(204,"SMTP: <--- \"%s\"", stri);
  if(stri[0] != '2' ) {
    error(ERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. HELO : %s",stri); 
    rc=4; goto LRET1;
  }

  char *from = conn->from;
  if(ACSAlarm ||
     fprintf(wfile,"MAIL FROM:<%s> %s\r\n", from,
         conn->from_tail? conn->from_tail: "") == EOF ||
     fflush(wfile) == EOF) {
    //    if (ACSAlarm) errno = ETIME;
    error(SYSERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. Can't send MAIL command.");
    rc = -1; goto LRET1;
  }
  debug(204,"SMTP: ---> MAIL FROM:<%s> %s", 
    from, conn->from_tail? conn->from_tail: "");

  if(ACSAlarm ||
     !fgets(stri,sizeof(stri),rfile)) {
    //    if (ACSAlarm) errno = ETIME;
    error(SYSERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. Can't get reply on MAIL.");
    rc = -1; goto LRET1;
  }
  delete_crnl(stri);
  debug(204,"SMTP <--- \"%s\"",stri);
  if(stri[0] != '2' ) {
    error(ERRMSG,"Talk Sendmail. MAIL : %s",stri); 
    rc=100; goto LRET1;
  }
```

Вы же, прочитав приветствие сервера, не отвечаете ему, а ждете от него данных, а он ждет их от Вас. Вот все и висит.